# Why so many same answers for a specific question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

It is hard to digest that there are so many same answers to one particular problem on Stackoverflow, and all of them have received so many upvotes. **If now I answer any of those questions, what would be the course of action or what practices will SO follow?** I know this question is more points hungry (and it is).

Comment: Why would you answer a question that's already been fully answered?

Comment: Not sure which question you are asking here - the one in your title or the one in the body?

Comment: exactly my point, why have people answered it even when a correct answer had been provided.

Comment: Difficult to say without a concrete example. Could be it was a simple question and a bunch of people each answered it at the same time - that's very common.

Comment: Some question can be solved by different methods, check for nuance in those answers that look identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's often more than one approach to a problem. Othertimes, people are posting at the same time (and I've often started typing an answer to find a similar one turns up).

Some folk go "eh, I know this" and post an answer similar to an existing one without really reading through all of em - or do read through all of them and do it anyway.

If it's a good answer, and *unique*, vote as you see fit. If it's a cynical copy of an existing answer, flag appropriately. If it's *seriously* awesome, and it's your question, and you already picked the 'correct' answer, consider picking.

In the context of SO alone, there's just so much traffic, it's more likely multiple people answer at once, or you get people who chose to answer anyway even if it's answered.

If you want to be a good citizen, only answer if you have something unique to add, that an existing answer does not. Amusingly, I've had excellent luck doing this on some other sites, even months after the original question was posted. It also reduces the chance that someone will assuming you're just going me too, and downvote, flag or vote to delete your answer.

Comment: well this helped me calm my anger... I wanted points but ‘eh, lets be a good citizen’ even those are in scarcity these days xD

Comment: Why are you angry?